# Detect and Build Dependencies for C# Solutions

Tags: c#, f#, build-process, build-dependencies

We have a Project with a number of different solutions files and each solution then has many projects. The problem is that there are projects that need to be built for certain solutions. Each developer has to go through the pain of opening a large solution (a solution that contains many projects). The problem is that these solutions don't always build because a certain build order has to be followed.

My question is, is there a way to identify dependencies for each project in a given directory and then build these projects. Something like find all the project files that don't have any dependencies on our other projects that we own. So build such projects first then build the ones whose dependencies are already built.

I was thinking of using F# or Fake to do this but I am not sure where to start or if it is even possible.

I would really appreciate an answer with an example or links to where I can get help.

Regards,

Nasir

Comment: "The problem is that these solutions don't always build because a certain build order has to be followed." That should be fixable within the solution settings.  You can explicitly set project dependencies to ensure they are built in the right order.

Comment: You can control the dependencies of the projects in a solution by right clicking on the solution in solution explorer, selecting properties then then project dependencies.  However I have never in my life had to touch them as VS just sorts it out based on the references.

Comment: Thanks guys, I understand all that but there are so many projects and when you are trying to build a solution that you haven't worked on for a while or are new to it, the developers end up spending a lot of time fixing the build rather than writing code. I was curious if there was a way to automate the building of all projects in a dependency order in a given folder.

Comment: @Nasir Why do your developers have to spend time fixing broken builds, do other developers commit broken builds to source control? Have you tried a CI system like CruiseControl.net or Team City or even TFS that builds on commit? If you check a solution out of source control, it should just build, if not then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @BenRobinson You are right, we are actually doing things wrong. I have discovered that to open some of the solutions to work on, you have to open and build other solutions. So if I want to work on solution A, I am having to open and build solution B because solution A is missing a few projects that are dependencies for other projects in the same solution. So to build them we are having to open solution B to build such projects. Now to  fix this, I'll add the required projects to solution A and it should work correctly.

Comment: @Nasir, that sounds like a strange setup, you must be referencing binaries in the bin folder of other solutions which is not good.  You should at least have a "references" folder or similar and then reference pre-build DLLs.  I would also look at building NuGet packages.  If you set up a Nuget repository and build your projects to that. Nuget will then handle resolving dependencies and you can update to the latest released version with a couple of mouse clicks with visual studio.

Comment: Another thing I wanted to clarify, is the question was about building the .net solution on the developer machine, the production builds in TFS work just fine. The problem was pulling down source code from TFS and then building a solution on the dev machine for debugging etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60244/discussion-between-nasir-and-ben-robinson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go with something off the shelf.  Resharper from JetBrains has a very nice tool for viewing project build dependencies.  This will help you create a build script with the correct build order.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Architecture__Project_Dependencies_Exploration.html

Comment: Thanks Ryan,
Yes we do use ReSharper and I have indeed looked at the feature you are talking about. As I mentioned some of the solutions are quite large and the diagram Resharper generate is virtually unreadable because of so many projects and the interdepencies shown. However, I have certainly identified this. And yes I can have a look at this and identify the problem and fix it. My intention for this post is not having to fix these issues but have a script that just automatically detects and builds the dependencies.

Comment: I see.  I have another idea, which again isn't what you are asking for, but might be a reasonable alternative.  Is it feasible use NuGet to help manage your dependencies?  You could have the various sub-projects create NuGet packages the top level projects pulled in that way.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing the analysis in F# yourself wouldn't be too complicated.

For example, you can do it in 2 phases:
1. Go through your solution folder structure and build a map of (project file name -> full path of file).
2. Go through all the files you found, and for each file add references to other solutions projects to a graph structure.

Then you build progressively projects that don't have any (yet unbuilt) references.

Project files are easy to parse, being XML. Solution projects can be recognised by the relative path reference:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\MyProjFolder\MyProjFile.csproj">
<!--                      --^                              -->
```

Comment: Thanks Mau, that is where I was struggling with F#. I am very new to F# hence the confusion on how to do it. I am currently trying to learn F# and will give it a go, but for now a nuget package sounds like the way to go.